# Technical approach to do / while

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while

Considering this:

```
var getToDaChoppa = false;

var warIsHell = function() {
    // Write your do/while loop here!
    do {
        console.log("I can't my legs omg my LEGS");
    } while (getToDaChoppa);
};

warIsHell();
```

and this

```
var getToDaChoppa = function() {
    var getToDaChoppa = false;
    do {
        console.log("I can't my legs omg my LEGS");
    } while (getToDaChoppa);
};

getToDaChoppa();
```

I really like to know which piece of code is better from a technical standpoint. (Lower memory usage, garbage generation, etc). I'm pretty n00b to js, but I want to make sure I'm writting the best possible code.

From my limited experience the second snippet will generate double garbage than the first one, but in the other hand, the first one uses double the memory than the second one, so I was wondering what is the best approach here. Ofc if you need to swing around variable values, ¿I understand first one is more versatile?, but I cannot fully comprenhend the pros / cons of both methods.

Any little explanation will be of great help o:)

Comment: Your random indentation makes your question harder to read.

Comment: Not experienced enough to know what are best practice on indentation. (Yes, such thing is possible). :(

Comment: Well, Joachim fixed it. The difference is that the content of the function is indented. Do it for any block.

Comment: thanks, I will get that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference I see between your two functions is that the first one uses a global (or at least external) variable while the second one use a local variable.

Then the rule is simple : don't declare a variable in an external scope if you don't use it in that scope. Always declare your variables in the most internal scope. This makes the code more readable and limits the risks of collision. Trying to reduce the garbaging by making it external is terrible practice and useless unless, in a very specific case, you proved by profiling you have a problem and it is solved that way (then... I won't probably trust you...).

A second rule would be : don't shadow variables if possible. Shadowing the name of the function with a boolean variable is very confusing.

Here's a "fixed" code :

```
var getToDaChoppa = function() {
    var finished = false;
    do {
        // some code, which hopefully will at some point set finished to true 
    } while (!finished); // you wanted a !, here, no ?
};
getToDaChoppa();
```

Comment: I will look for more information about that "shadowing" pitfall, but your code example makes it perfectly clear. A best practice is to be very aware of varible names and when to use them. thx. :)

Comment: @Malcomiles To shadow a variable of an external scope is to make it invisible by giving the same name to another variable in an internal scope.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the second approach is better simply because you're keeping the condition variable inside the function scope, thus not polluting the global scope.

Also, don't name the variable with the same name as the function.

Comment: Thanks, so naming conventions are far more important than I first though.